# React native stack navigator : how to pass params?? i can't pass params

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-navigation, react-props

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EOT2V.png)

this is structure of project.
i want to operate it: when is press ReportButton, navigate to ReportScreen with post's title parameter(props)

this is stack of App.js

```
<NavigationContainer>
        <Stack.Navigator initialRouteName="Main">
          <Stack.Screen name="Main" component={MainScreen} />
          <Stack.Screen name="Report" component={ReportScreen} />
        </Stack.Navigator>
      </NavigationContainer>
```

this is tap navigator of mainscreen

```
<Tab.Navigator initialRouteName="Home" tabBarOptions={{showIcon: true}}>
      <Tab.Screen
        name="Main"
        options={{
          tabBarLabel: 'main',
          tabBarIcon: ({color}) => <Icon name="home" color={color} size={24} />,
          tabBarColor: 'blue',
        }}
        component={MapScreen}
      />
      <Tab.Screen
        name="Feed"
        options={{
          tabBarLabel: 'feed',
          tabBarIcon: ({color}) => <Icon name="home" color={color} size={24} />,
          tabBarColor: 'blue',
        }}
        component={FeedScreen}
      />
      <Tab.Screen
        name="Setting"
        options={{
          tabBarLabel: 'setting',
          tabBarIcon: ({color}) => <Icon name="home" color={color} size={24} />,
          tabBarColor: 'blue',
        }}
        component={SettingScreen}
      />
</Tab.Navigator>
```

this is part of ReportButton to navigate

```
    <TouchableOpacity
        style={postModalStyles.listButton} 
        onPress={()=>{console.log(post.title); navigation.navigate('Report', { title: post.title 
    });}}>
                <Text style={postModalStyles.text}>report</Text>
    </TouchableOpacity>
```

this is part of ReportScreen

```
const ReportScreen = ({title}) => {
   console.log(title);
   return(
     <View></View>
   );
}
```

output of node.js console

```
 LOG  hello world //log of reportbutton 's post.title
 LOG  undefined //log of reportscreen's post.title
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not passing props ,
when you do navigate , you pass **'params'**

so you should do this in reportScreen :

```
const ReportScreen = ({ navigation, route }) => {
   console.log(route.params?.title);
   return(
     <View></View>
   );
}
```